# "Error no label add or removes specified" when trying to modify labels using Gmail's Node.js API

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, gmail-api

I'm trying to modify the labels of emails in my inbox using gmail's Node.js API. My function to mark an email as read and star it is:

```
function markAsRead(auth, req, res)
{
    var gmail = google.gmail('v1');
    console.log(req.body.id);
    gmail.users.messages.modify({
        auth: auth,
        id: req.body.id,
        userId: 'me',
        resouce:
            {
                "addLabelIds": [
                    "STARRED"
                ],
                "removeLabelIds": [
                    "UNREAD"
                ]
            }

    }, function(err, response) {
        if (err) 
        {
            console.log('...The API returned an error: ' + err);
            return;
        }
        console.log("Success???");
    });
}
```

It gives an error saying No label add or removes specified. I've checked the email objects coming in and in their labelIds attributes "UNREAD" and "STARRED" appear so they're valid labelIds.
I seem to be doing what the [docs for the API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/modify) say is correct but it keeps giving that same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks good. I think it's just a typo. `resouce` should be `resource`.